# TensorFlow lookup table/dictionary

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am optimising a variable, `var1`. This parameterises a matrix, `H_guess`.

This matrix is quite slow to compute, so I thought it would be wiser to pre-compute a bunch of these matrices, for different values of `var1` ahead of time, and store them in a dictionary. I can then use a look-up table to find the best `H_guess` from my dictionary during inference by finding the closest match between the current estimate of `var1` and the dictionary keys.

However, unsurprisingly, when setup this way, there is no gradient flow from `var1` durin the look-up process.

Is there a more sensible/possible way of updating `var1` via gradient descent, and using that value which is being optimised to find the corresponding index for `precomputed_H_guess`, and then updating it to minimise the loss?

**Code:**

```
# Create dictionary

# Define a range of values for var1 * channel_positions_x
var1 =np.linspace(-2,2,10)

# Create an empty dictionary to store precomputed H_guess matrices
precomputed_H_guess = {}

# Loop through the range and precompute H_guess matrices
for val in var1:
    
    current_var1_x = val
    
    H_guess = generate_H(
        val*channel_positions_x,
        channel_positions_y,
        channel_positions_z,
        quick_cast_32(source_positions[:, 0]),
        quick_cast_32(source_positions[:, 1]),
        quick_cast_32(source_positions[:, 2]),
        orientations,
    )
    H_guess = tf.cast(H_guess, dtype=tf.float32)
    H_guess = tf.transpose(H_guess[:, :, 0])
    
    # Store the computed H_guess in the dictionary
    precomputed_H_guess[current_var1_x] = H_guess

def find_nearest_key(dictionary, value):
    nearest_key = min(dictionary.keys(), key=lambda x: abs(x - value))
    return nearest_key

...

# Define the optimization process
best_cost = np.inf

# Define the optimization process
learning_rate = 0.01  # was 0.01
optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate)

# Lists to store costs for visualization
costs = []

alpha_1_sample=tf.Variable(alpha_1_gt,trainable=False,dtype=tf.float32)
alpha_2_sample = tf.constant(alpha_2_gt, dtype=tf.float32)

var1= tf.Variable(2.0,trainable=True,dtype=tf.float32)

for iteration in range(NUM_ITERATIONS_MAIN_LOOP):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        
        nearest_key = find_nearest_key(precomputed_H_guess, var1)
        nearest_H_guess = precomputed_H_guess[nearest_key]

        # Calculate the negative log likelihood cost
        neg_log_likelihood = alternative_loss_function_rank_def_matrices(
            C_Y_tf, nearest_H_guess, alpha_2_sample * beta_2_tf, alpha_1_sample * beta_1_tf
        )

        total_cost = neg_log_likelihood

    # Calculate & apply gradients
    gradients = tape.gradient(
        total_cost,
        [var1],
    )


    optimizer.apply_gradients(
        zip(
            gradients,
            [var1],
        )
    )
```

**Error message:**

```
site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/utils.py in filter_empty_gradients(grads_and_vars)
     73 
     74   if not filtered:
---> 75     raise ValueError("No gradients provided for any variable: %s." %
     76                      ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],))
     77   if vars_with_empty_grads:

ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['Variable:0'].
```

Comment: The problem is that you never do computations with `var1`, yet ask for a gradient to `var1`. Where should TensorFlow compute that? You only use the approximation `nearest_H_guess`. I think you could only compute the gradient between `nearest_H_guess` and `total_cost`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I understand that this is the source of the issue, but do you have any tips as to how I could get around this? Could I do something like define tensors when creating my dictionary, and use them for subsequent gradient calculations?

Comment: If you want to use `nearest_H_guess` for the gradient, you can initialize them as `x=tf.Variable(x)`, or add `tape.watch(x)` as the first line inside the GradientTape. Here, `x` is your `nearest_H_guess`. You also have to calculate the gradient with respect to `nearest_H_guess`, so: `tape.gradient(total_cost, x)`. You could also combine this with the recommendation of Asif, but remember to calculate the gradients of the value you actually use in the calculations.

Comment: Thanks @mhenning. I have added nearest_`H_guess = tf.Variable(precomputed_H_guess[nearest_key])` inside the optimisation loop and updated the grad calcultion and update accordingly.  `gradients = tape.gradient(
        total_cost,
        [nearest_H_guess,var1],
    )


    optimizer.apply_gradients(
        zip(
            gradients,
            [nearest_H_guess,var1],
        )
    )`, but I want to optimise `var1`, rather than `nearest_H_guess` (the look-up value). Have I missed something?

Comment: If you want to optimize `var1` directly and not the `H_guess` of `var1` (whatever the H is), I think you have no other chance than to introduce the `generate_H` math into your gradient step. Otherwise you just have half-calculated gradients in regards to `var1`, as you never have the gradients for the `generate_H` math. Currently, this step is completely outside of your gradient calculation.